# What makes AUTH PLAIN work and not AUTH LOGIN and vice versa?

Tags: openssl, postfix-mta, dovecot

I don't understand why, with identical versions of Postfix/Dovecot/Openssl, and very close configurations, on one server I can auth with AUTH LOGIN and not with AUTH PLAIN, and on the other, that's the contrary.

```
# openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect localhost:587
```

Server 1:

```
read R BLOCK
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
###username_coded_base64###
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
###password_coded_base64###
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

```
read R BLOCK
AUTH PLAIN ###username+password_coded_base64###
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
```

Server 2:

```
read R BLOCK
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
###username_coded_base64###
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
###password_coded_base64###
RENEGOTIATING
40F7446F017F0000:error:0A00010A:SSL routines:can_renegotiate:wrong ssl version:../openssl-3.0.10/ssl/ssl_lib.c:2304:
```

```
read R BLOCK
AUTH PLAIN ###username+password_coded_base64###
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

###username_coded_base64### and ###password_coded_base64### produced by : `echo -ne "string" | base64`

###username_coded_base64### produced by : `echo -ne "\000username\000password" | base64`

```
postfix-3.8.1
dovecot-2.3.20-r1
openssl-3.0.10
```

**Edit1:**

The problem on `Server 1` with `AUTH PLAIN` was about the way to encode the string.

```
echo -ne "\000username\000password" | base64
```

doesn't work, but:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("\000username\000password")'
```

doesn't give the same result, and this one works !

For `Server 2` I never found why `AUTH LOGIN` doesn't work totally but I realized that it works for virtual users but not for local users. I'm still looking for why. May be something about dovecot configuration...